# Excel VBA identify pivotItems visible in excel interface

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My pivot table contains a Filter to filter items with `"Days_Outstnading_Category"=">180 days"`.

[image]

Once filtered, my row field `"Operating Units"` only has 2 items showing in excel interface, "US" and "India", although all items in "Operating Units" has `Visible=True`, there are really only 2 items actually visible in the excel interface.

I wonder how I can identify those two items, since the `If pivotItem.Visible=True` won't work now.

Ultimately I wanted to iterate and select the LabelRange for each item appear in excel interface(A5:A12, A14:A27, B5,B6:B9, etc.) and do some formatting changes to each range.  And my code below brings an error where labelrange cannot be found.

```
> For Each ptRowField In pt.RowFields
>      For Each ptRowFieldItem In ptRowField.PivotItems
>          If ptRowFieldItem.Visible = True Then
>              Call SetOusideBorder(ptRowFieldItem.LabelRange)
>          End If
>      Next ptRowFieldItem 
> Next ptRowField
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I've used is to grab the column in the PivotTable that has your row labels.

In my sample data set, I have seven colors: Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, and Violet. I've set up the data and created a pivot table, then filtered it so only three of the colors are showing:

[image]

So you can access the column of row labels in the pivot table with the `.RowRange` property. Once you have that, you can step down the cells:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListVisibleItems()
    Dim thisPivot As PivotTable
    Set thisPivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    Dim rowField As PivotField
    Set rowField = thisPivot.RowFields("Color")

    Dim theseRows As Range
    Set theseRows = thisPivot.RowRange

    Dim i As Long
    '--- start at 2 to skip the "Row Labels" and end at Count-1
    '    to skip the "Grand Total" 
    For i = 2 To theseRows.Count - 1
        Debug.Print theseRows.Cells(i, 1) & " is visible"
    Next i
End Sub
```

> **EDIT:** updated example code to parse the OP's example data

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListVisibleItems()
    Dim thisPivot As PivotTable
    Set thisPivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    Dim rowField As PivotField
    Set rowField = thisPivot.RowFields("Color")

    Dim theseRows As Range
    Set theseRows = thisPivot.RowRange

    Dim i As Long
    '--- start at 2 to skip the "Operating Units" and end at Count-1
    '    to skip the "Grand Total" 
    For i = 2 To theseRows.Count - 1
        '--- check to make sure the row is not empty and that
        '    the value does NOT have the word "Total"
        If Len(theseRows.Cells(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            If Not theseRows.Cells(i, 1) Like "*Total" Then
                Debug.Print theseRows.Cells(i, 1) & " is visible"
                '--- you can use this result as the field name
                '    to select and format the data area
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for providing a good way to iterate.  However, for my own data (sorry it's sensitive so I cannot do screenshot), one fielditem can occupy different lines, with the item name in the first line and rest lines empty.  I wanted to select all lines belong to that specific item and do some formatting changes. Also the layout I was using is tabular.  Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: If you can produce an example as a screenshot, that would help. It doesn't even have to be a real pivot table, just a small range of cells formatted to look like one to illustrate your problem. Change the names in your fields to use colors or animal names or something. I can possible provide a little better guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Go read [Jon Peltier's page on pivot tables](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) and specifically look at `DataRange` and `LabelRange` to see if that helps.

Comment: I've actually read it before.  In his example I have to specify the name of the pivot item to get label range, like "pt.PivotFields("Years").PivotItems("2004").LabelRange.Select".  I'm trying to find out the item's names and feed into this function now, because if some items are not visible in excel interface, they don't have label range.

Comment: I've updated the answer to hopefully address what you're asking